# sen2cor 2.4.0 on SNAP 6.0

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-snap, sen2cor

Apparently, the new released SNAP 6.0 allows the sen2cor plugin to be installed and run directly within the SNAP. Indeed, SNAP installs the bundle when try to run it.

However, it doesn't work for me. Although a new folder is generated (S2A_MSIL1A...from the S2A_MSIL1C), the folder does not contain the corrected bands.

Is there anyone that succeeded with it without using Anaconda nor the standalone sen2cor tool?

I enter the image through the MTD_MSIL1C file within the download folder S2A_MSIL1C_...

Then I run the sen2cor  and a new folder is generated named S2A_MSIL2A_...

But inside the latter folder I just have two empty folders: AUX_DATA and DATASTRIP

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: S2A_MSIL1A or S2A_MSIL2A? Why aren't the correct bands on folder?

Comment: I enter the image through the MTD_MSIL1C file within the download folder S2A_MSIL1C_...

Then I run the sen2cor  and a new folder is generated named S2A_MSIL2A_...

But inside the latter folder I just have two empty folders: AUX_DATA and DATASTRIP

Any suggestion?

Comment: Let me try with v. 6.0. The bands are in Granule folder

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I will looking forward. Hopefully it could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Sen2cor? Did you follow [this procedure?](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/sen2cor-2-4-0-stand-alone-installers-how-to-install/6908)

I installed SNAP v 6.0 and [download Sen2cor 2.4 stand-alone installer](http://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/sen2cor/) follow [the procedure mentioned in STEP forum](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/sen2cor-2-4-0-stand-alone-installers-how-to-install/6908). I've set environmental variables in SNAP too, it's the most important part to be successful:

[image]

[image]

I was careful, but setting could be:

- `SEN2COR_HOME` = `$USER_HOME`
- `SEN2COR_BIN` = `$SEN2COR_HOME/bin` or `$SEN2COR_HOME\bin` in Windows
- `SEN2COR_EXE` = `$SEN2COR_BIN/L2A_Process` or `$SEN2COR_BIN\L2A_Process` in Windows
- `USERPROFILE` = `~`
- `HOME` = `/Users/your_user` in OS X, or `C:\Users\your_user\` in Windows
- `USER_HOME` = `$HOME`

With this configuration, bands are created without problem:

[image]

Comment: Dear Aldo Thank you for your reply. Actually it seems kind of strange because following the procedure the sen2cor works on one computer but not on others PC. Well at any rate I can work on it on one PC at least.

Comment: @Nico_77 Did you tried to run Sen2cor in command line?

Comment: Yes I tried but I not succeded

Comment: Anyway I have read that next version of SNAP will fix the issue

Comment: @Nico_77 by the information that you give me I think is not a SNAP issue, maybe you're trying to make it run in a 32bit computer